# ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

I'm developing a deep learning model with tensor flow and python:

- First, using CNN layers, get features.
- Second, reshaping the feature map, I want to use LSTM layer.

However, a error with not-matching dimension...

ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: `shape[0] = [71,48]` vs. `shape[1] = [1200,24]`

```
W_conv1 = weight_variable([1,conv_size,1,12])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([12])

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1)+ b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_1xn(h_conv1)

W_conv2 = weight_variable([1,conv_size,12,24])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([24])

h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_1xn(h_conv2)

W_conv3 = weight_variable([1,conv_size,24,48])
b_conv3 = bias_variable([48])

h_conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool2, W_conv3) + b_conv3)
h_pool3 = max_pool_1xn(h_conv3)


print(h_pool3.get_shape())
h3_rnn_input = tf.reshape(h_pool3, [-1,x_size/8,48])

num_layers = 1
lstm_size = 24
num_steps = 4

lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(lstm_size, initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform = False))
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell]*num_layers)
init_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size,tf.float32)


cell_outputs = []
state = init_state
with tf.variable_scope("RNN") as scope:
for time_step in range(num_steps):
    if time_step > 0: scope.reuse_variables() 
    cell_output, state = cell(h3_rnn_input[:,time_step,:],state) ***** Error In here...
```

Answer (score 5):

When you input to the rnn cell, the batch size of input tensor and state tensor should be same.

In the error message, it says `h3_rnn_input[:,time_step,:]` has shape of `[71,48]` while `state` has shape of `[1200,24]`

What you need to do is make the first dimensions(batch_size) to be same.

If the number 71 is not intended, check the Convolution part. Stride/Padding Could be matter.

Answer (score 0):

you must consider the right number for
h3_rnn_input[:,time_step,:]
and
state
in order to dose not have any remaining by batch_size division.(if has any remain error will be raise)

so, about your code:

```
h3_rnn_input[:,time_step,:] has shape of [71,48]
state has shape of [1200,24]
```

if we consider batch_size for example equal to 90 then:

```
71/90=0.78 ===> error
1200/90=13.33 ===> error
```

but if we consider shapes and batch size as below, then we don't have any problem:

```
h3_rnn_input[:,time_step,:] has shape of [**60**,48]
state has shape of [**1200**,24]
batch_size=30
```

then

```
60/30=2 ======> ok without any error
1200/30=40 ======> ok without any error
```