# Tensorflow error with ConvLSTMCell: Dimensions of inputs should match

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, convolution, recurrent-neural-network

I tried to feed in the `ConvLSTMCell` input arguments based on the Tensorflow documentation but still, I am getting this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [10,64,64,1] vs. shape[1] = [1,64,64,16]
     [[Node: rnn/while/rnn/Encoder_1/concat = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](rnn/while/TensorArrayReadV3, rnn/while/Switch_4:1, rnn/while/rnn/Encoder_1/split/split_dim)]]
```

My code is:

```
num_channels = 1
img_size = 64
filter_size1 = 5 
num_filters1 = 16
#If time_major == True, this must be a Tensor of shape: [max_time, batch_size, ...], or a nested tuple of such elements.
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,1, img_size, img_size, num_channels], name='x')
InputShape = [img_size,img_size, 1]
encoder_1_KernelShape = [filter_size1,filter_size1]
# create a ConvLSTMCell
rnn_cell = ConvLSTMCell(2, InputShape, num_filters1, encoder_1_KernelShape, use_bias=True, forget_bias=1.0, name='Encoder_1')

# 'outputs' is a tensor of shape [batch_size, max_time, cell_state_size]

# defining initial state
#initial_state = rnn_cell.zero_state(batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)
initial_state = rnn_cell.zero_state(1, dtype=tf.float32)
# 'state' is a tensor of shape [batch_size, cell_state_size]
encoder_1_outputs, encoder_1_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(rnn_cell, x,
                                   initial_state=initial_state,
                                   dtype=tf.float32)

for i in range(2):
    x_train = data_3[0:10, i, :, :]
    x_train = x_train.flatten()
    x_train = x_train.reshape([10, 1, img_size, img_size, 1])
    x_train = np.float32(x_train)
    feed_dict_train = {x: x_train}
```

Comment: the same problem has been answered in this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41088064/concatop-dimensions-of-inputs-should-match/62784522#62784522

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
num_channels = 1
img_size = 64
filter_size1 = 5
num_filters1 = 16

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,None,img_size,img_size,num_channels],
                   name='x')
InputShape = [img_size, img_size, num_channels]
encoder_1_KernelShape = [filter_size1, filter_size1]
rnn_cell = ConvLSTMCell(2, InputShape, num_filters1, encoder_1_KernelShape,
                        use_bias=True, forget_bias=1.0, name='Encoder_1')

initial_state = rnn_cell.zero_state(10, dtype=tf.float32)
encoder_1_outputs, encoder_1_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(rnn_cell, x,
                                                       initial_state=initial_state,
                                                       dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  x_train = np.zeros([10, 1, img_size, img_size, num_channels], dtype=np.float32)
  sess.run(encoder_1_outputs, feed_dict={x: x_train})
```

Note that the first dimension in `x` is the `batch_size` (equals 10 in the example) and the second one is `sequence_num` (equals 1).

Comment: Thanks!
Your code worked. So if I want to feed 10 sequences at the same time the second dimension of x would be 10? @Maxim

Comment: Another question: Shouldn't I use "rnn_cell.LSTMCell.zero_state(batch_size, dtype)" instead of "rnn_cell.zero_state", if yes, then the first input is the number of frames in one sequence or the number of sequences I feed each time? Thanks a lot @Maxim

Comment: `batch_size` and `sequence_num` are independent, so you can change 1 to any value, it will only affect the length of RNN (number of cells from `dynamic_rnn`). And using `rnn_cell.zero_state` is better, because the input state should correspond to the cell argument in `dynamic_rnn`

Comment: with this setup I for "encoder_1_state.h" I get: <tf.Tensor 'rnn/while/Exit_4:0' shape=(10, 64, 64, 16) dtype=float32>. But I want one representation of the whole 10 pictures of the sequence, in other words, I want the model to learn the temporal trend in the data. @Maxim

Comment: Look closely: 10 is the batch size, not sequence length. The state always accumulates all pictures in a sequence.