# Error using dynamic rnn (magenta) : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [1,38] vs. shape[1] = [128,512]

Tags: python, tensorflow, magenta

So I am running this code from magenta with some modifications:

```
outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
                self.cell,
                m_seq,
                sequence_length=lens,
                initial_state=initial_state,
                swap_memory=swap_memory,
                parallel_iterations=parallel_iterations)
```

where `self.cell` is a MultiRNN cell with two layers, `m_seq` is a one hot length vector with shape [1,38] and `state` is a tuple of two `LSTMStateTuple`'s with `c` and `h` having shape [128,512] (batch size and layer size).

When I run this I get:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [1,38] vs. shape[1] = [128,512]

Now I understand that this means a mismatch between the input `m_seq` and the state. However, do both of the dimensions have to match (1 and 128, 38 and 512)? I do not really understand why this would be the case ie. why they have to match at all, since this is a dynamic rnn.

Answer (score 0):

From [dynamic RNN docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn):

> The first two dimensions must match across all the inputs, but otherwise the ranks and other shape components may differ.

So the input dimensions have to match even though it is a dynamic RNN.

Comment: That is referring to the inputs. We only have one input so the dimensions do match across all inputs. The problem is between the input shape and the state shape. Let me know if I am missing something

Comment: are you referring to state or initial_state?

Comment: I'm referring to intial_state

Answer (score 0):

[ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41088064/concatop-dimensions-of-inputs-should-match)

I believe this answers my question. The batch-size (first argument) must match, but the second one (sequence-length) does not need to match because it is a dynamic RNN. In any case, it is possible to use a placeholder to adopt varying batch-sizes.